# Passing a command line argument input file to a class to parse

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

There is probably a very simple solution to my problem but I am having some problems passing an input file (from command line arguments) into a class for parsing.

Here is the relevant part of my main.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "SortingCompetition.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid arguments" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Usage: ./a.out <input file> <output file>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SortingCompetition sorter(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the SortingCompetition.h file:

```
#ifndef SORTINGCOMPETITION_H_
#define SORTINGCOMPETITION_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class SortingCompetition{
private:
    string& input_;
    vector<string> data_;
public:
    SortingCompetition(const string& inputFileName);
    void setFileName(const string& inputFileName);
    bool readData();
    bool prepareData();
    void sortData();
    void outputData(const string& outputFileName);
};

#endif
```

All the functions must remain the same here. i.e. 
`SortingCompetition(const string& inputFileName);`
must stay that way... I cannot remove the `const` or anything else.

Here is the relevant implementation of SortingCompetition:

```
#include "SortingCompetition.h"

SortingCompetition::SortingCompetition(const string& inputFileName){
    input_ = inputFileName;
}
void SortingCompetition::setFileName(const string& inputFileName){
    input_ =  inputFileName;
}
```

This is where I'm getting problems, I'm not passing the input file from the command argument to the private variable correctly. I've searched for quite a while, but cannot find a solution.

Comment: What's the point where "parsing" is important? I don't think it's related.

Comment: In the `readData` function, I'm trying to parse the input file:        `bool SortingCompetition::readData(){
 string temp;
 input_ >> temp;`

Comment: Oh aha. Is there another question about that then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing it correctly, but you're storing a reference to temporary. This is the problem.

Change:

```
class SortingCompetition{
private:
    string input_;  // THIS LINE
    vector<string> data_;
```

This copies the *value* so it doesn't matter that the parameter to the constructor (or `setFilename`) was only a temporary

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what do I change it to? If I stick a `const` in there I can't parse it anymore.